# Error using Multi Data bases in Laravel 5.1 runing with xampp

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I followed this page:
http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections
for create a select to another data base, but i get this error:

QueryException in Connection.php line 636:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'data1.table2' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `table2` limit 1)

is taking the 1er database with the 2th table

I have this conf with my external respective ip xx.xx.xxx.xxx :
.....

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'data1'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],

'upc2' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'the external ip'),
    'port'      => '3306',
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'data2'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user2'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass2'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

.....

and

.....

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=UpitzXsqg7pwNwwHbKfOnzDmMRbcE4qa

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=data1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

UPC2_HOST=my external ip
UPC2_PORT=3306
UPC2_DATABASE=data2
UPC2_USERNAME=user2
UPC2_PASSWORD=pass2

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

....

and

in my model

....

```
 protected $connection = 'upc2';

 /**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $table = 'table2';
```

.....

anyone know what is happening ?

Comment: new friend findstar show me the error.

Comment: Your test query (as shown in your post) is SQL instead of using the object model: Can you verify the code around that query that you are using the correct database connection at that location in your code? (Or: Post more code related to where the error occurs)

Answer (score 1):

you should change your database.php file

like this.

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'data1'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],

'upc2' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('UPC2_HOST', 'the external ip'),
    'port'      => '3306',
    'database'  => env('UPC2_DATABASE', 'data2'),
    'username'  => env('UPC2_USERNAME', 'user2'),
    'password'  => env('UPC2_PASSWORD', 'pass2'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

env function get value from .env file

you shuld right name.